# Get DNN Profile Properties In Skin

Tags: properties, themes, dotnetnuke, profile, skin

I can get thing like the user's email with something like this

```
<% =UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Email %>
```

But how can I get a custom created profile property to display in the skin?

The closest thing I could find was something like this:

```
UserProfile.GetPropertyValue("Company");
```

But I get this error:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserProfile.GetPropertyValue(string)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to start from the current user, so it would be something like this:

```
UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Profile.GetPropertyValue("Company")
```